# Trying to run a VBA code which generates error91

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code for copying the value of corresponding cell depending on value of another cell but i am getting the *error 91*. can you please see what i am doing wrong. getting error on

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, Snags As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long, lrSnags As Long, i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Snags" Then
        lr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lr
            lrSnags = Snags.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If ws.Range("B") = "Fail" Then
                ws.Range("A" & i).Copy
                Snags.Range("A" & lrSnags).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next ws
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Complete"

End Sub
```

getting error at below line

```
lrSnags = Snags.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Comment: You have declared  `Snags` but never assigned anything to it.  Probably you are missing a statement like `set Snags = Worksheets("Snags")` before you enter the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess you did not define your worksheet named "Snags"

You need to set `Snags` after defining it: 
For ex with:

```
   Set Snags = Worksheets("Snags")
```

Alternatively you can just change your line without defining it to:

```
lrSnags = Sheets("Snags").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre for you help. is it possible for you to review my code as i m new and still getting alot of error. what i want to do is i have multiple sheets(sheet1, sheet2,.... and SNAGS) which have three columns in each sheets except SNAGS Sheet(Description, Result and Notes)


so for each description user can either put pass or fail in result column. What i want to do is in the whole workbook if any cell has a value "Fail", the corresponding value of description cell should be copied in a sheet "SNAGS" which is already added.

Comment: I guess this is a different question. You should post a new question with your code and remarks then more people will see and help you (if you comment here, I m almost the only one to see it)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. i will post as a new question

Comment: I cant add anymore question for 3 days. see if you can help otherwise i will have to wait

Comment: I ll have a look. Btw you cannot ask question for three days because of your question from the 7th october which was not well received https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited

Comment: Yes, i know. anyways i got it to work. Thanks for your support. really appreciate that